# RecyclerView with dynamic Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have created my `RcyclerView` and its adapter like following.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int count = list.size();
        list.add(count + " * 10 = " + (count * 10));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

And my `adapter`'s ViewHolder is

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    EditText item;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        item = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        item.requestFocus(); //I want my last row's EditText get focused automatically.
    }
}
```

So I want my last `EditText` get focused automatically. But when I add new one last edittext get focused, while add new one again then first one get focused, then last one, then first one.. etc... Please refer the gif.

[image]

Here it shouldn't go to the first edittext.

I don't know how to stable this issue.

Comment: The second last paragraph is really confusing. Can you please make it clearer?

Comment: @NabinKhadka, Give me one minute, I will upload gif

Comment: @NabinKhadka, Added GIF, please refer it.

Comment: try requestFocus() in on bindViewHolder method..

Comment: @Androidjack, Tried, but doesn't work

Comment: Did you tried instead of calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to call `adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);`

Comment: Try to call `layoutManager.findViewByPosition(list.size() - 1).findViewById(R.id.item).requestFocus()`?

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin, I have tried and it also doesn't work. I have added answer which is worked for me.

Comment: @ZhangXiang , I didn't tried yours, But I have added the answer which is worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

By using following method I have achieved the target. Thanks for all who tried to help me.

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    if (holder.item != null && holder.item.getText().length() == 0) {
        holder.item.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: why this happened?

Comment: @Androidjack, It is big story, I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: In onclick method if we set the adapter again it works.Is it right to set adapter instead of using notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @Androidjack, No, You have to set adapter for recyclerview only one time. After that you have to notify your adapter. This is the best practice. Because If you are using to set adapter always you can't trace your current adapter.